# Is it possible to implement bottom tab bar functionality like iOS in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost

In iOS , bottom tab bar functionality is very basic. But in android , I can't implement this functionality.
My idea is as follows.
Tab bar contains SMS, Call, Camera - 3 tab bar icons.
Whenever taps this icons, I want to run SMS, Phone call and Camera installed on my android device.
But these should be the same as iOS tab View. (shouldn't be full screen)
I have found solution for a long time, but I can't find the correct way.
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in the XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/home_background_color"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:tabPadding="10dp"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/app_primary_color"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

and this in the code

```
 try
    {
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon1);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon2);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon3);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon4);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("TabLayout Creation Error",e.getMessage());
    }



    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
switch(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition())
    {
    case 0:

break;
        case 1:
//Do the stuff
break;
        case 2:
//Do the stuff
break;
        case 3:
//Do the stuff
break;
        }
     }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, But I think it is not the way we can show apps installed on android device. I am trying but they shows me full-screen simultaneously, tab bar doesn't show.

Comment: Man you need to put intents inside each case of the switch that launches the respective app you want by a specific intent, this is the answer of your question else than that you need to clarify your question of what you want

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have already tried it. Then, May I ask you one question? Can you run installed app in some LinearLayout? I am looking forward for your reply. Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: that what is your question in specific ?

Comment: Is it possible to show SMS, Call, Camera with Tab bar?

Comment: u said that you have found the solution long ago but it wont work with you? why dont you edit your question and put the solution you have found so that we can help you

Comment: Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible tab bar in bottom
try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:divider="@drawable/bg_tab_seperator"
            android:dividerPadding="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, But I think it is not the way we can show apps installed on android device. I am trying but they shows me full-screen simultaneously, tab bar doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented what youre saying in one my apps..ill post the xm shortly

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager    
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"    
                android:layout_height="match_parent"    
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"    
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_above="@+id/app_bar"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout    
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"    
                android:layout_width="match_parent"    
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"    
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:background="@color/background"
                >

                <com.****.****.ui.custom.IconTextTabLayout    
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"    
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed" />
            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my `<com.****.****.ui.custom.IconTextTabLayout` is nothing but a class which extends `TabLayout` you can use the default widget.