# Change button with swipe in Android

Tags: android

I'm making custom camera app and I need to create a camera buttons like picture, video and time laps button as similar to instagram camera. I can create a design similar to these buttons but problem is that I can't move them like that.
If you see in Instagram as shown in picture By default its show picture button but I want to change it when someone swipe finger on it.

Here is image of instagram camera

[image: Instagram camera]

As you can see in image when user swipe on white ball it moved to next **BOOMERANG** and so on and back and forth. 
Or if user click on any text which is at the bottom of screen it scroll set in the middle right above the arrow.
I want similar functionality But I don't know how to achieve this because I'm new in android. Can you please let me know what I need to read for this.
Thanks.

Comment: ViewPager would be the quickest solution here. Otherwise, you need a custom view and know how to deal with animation

Comment: @cricket_007 viewPager for swipe and what for Scrolling textviews at the bottom of image. Any tutorial ?

Comment: @cricket_007 are you there ? can you please provide me some more info please

Comment: I don't have tutorials and asking for them is off topic here. The official documentation for ViewPager is simple enough, but it doesn't do what you are asking. I would suggest you continue searching for the phrase "implementing Instagram bottom bar"... For example **first result**  https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Comment: Or simply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955494/is-it-possible-to-implement-bottom-tab-bar-functionality-like-ios-in-android

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, But I'm not talking about that bottom bar which you provide me link I'm talking about the bar which is shown in image `Live, Noramal, Bommering` I'm talking about this one. Problem is that I'm not know what is that can you please let me know what I search on google ?

Comment: That link I sent you has labels for the icons, yes? I don't understand what you're saying is different. It's simply a "bottom bar" holding a list of labeled images. I don't know how else to describe it

Comment: If you only want the labels, then, that's simply a thin ViewPager with an arrow for the page

Comment: @cricket_007 as I searched ViewPager is used to show Fragments or layouts. But I don't want to show any fragment. Your mean I used ViewPager for swipe function ?

Comment: ViewPager is for swiping between views. You aren't limited to Fragments